# PHP - preg_match - check if string contains year which is between 1950 and 2010

Tags: php

How do I check with preg_match if string contains year which is between 1950 and 2010 ?

example:

$string = "I was born in 1986 year.";

Comment: Are you trying to check if today's year is between those years? Or is it an arbitrary year?

Comment: More detail please. Are you given a "year" or "timestamp" or "string representation of date" or what?

Comment: Your update didn't really clarify the question much. Is your string formatted in a certain way? Is it just an arbitrary string? Why do you have to use preg_match instead of `strtotime()`? Some examples would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string is already formatted in a way that can be consumed by `getdate()`, the other answers would be the best solution.

If the string is just some random text which might or might not contain a date, you'd need to use a regex to find those numbers.

`/(19[5-9][0-9]|20(0[0-9]|10))/`

Of course, you have no guarantee that the numbers matched this way is actually a year. It could be 2005 pounds of steel or 1976 miles of highway.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a timestamp:

```
$date = getdate($timestamp);
if ($date['year'] >= 1950 && $date['year'] <= 2010)
  return 'good';
```

Comment: and if you dont have a timestamp you get one with `strtotime` or use `date_parse`

Comment: for regular number is => ([0-9]{1,})

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = getdate( $timestamp );
if( (int)$date['year'] >= 1950 && (int)$date['year'] <= date('Y') ) {
   return 'good';
}
```

:P

```
if( preg_match( '/^(19[5-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|20(0[0-9]{1}|10))$/', $i ) ) {}
// tested - works. 1950-2010
```